# Model Object weird result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  TYPE = {:admin => "Administrator", :owner => "Owner", :client => "Customer"}

  # some codes here
end
```

When I run below code in rails console:

```
User::TYPE
```

Output:

```
{:admin => "Administrator", :owner => "owner", :client => "Customer"}
```

And when I add the code in controller:

```
 User::TYPE
```

This is the output:

```
[
  {
    "user_types": {
      "user": "Administrator",
      "owner": "owner",
      "client": "Customer"
    }
  },
  {
    "user_types": {
      "user": "Administrator",
      "owner": "owner",
      "client": "Customer"
    }
  },
  {
    "user_types": {
      "user": "Administrator",
      "owner": "owner",
      "client": "Customer"
    }
  }
]
```

And I only I need:

```
{
    "user_types": {
      "user": "Administrator",
      "owner": "owner",
      "client": "Customer"
    }
```

What I am doing wrong here. I also tried `User::TYPE` but I don't get the correct result.

UPDATE:

Here is my controller code:

```
def user_types
  @user_types = User::TYPE
end
```

In my view to show the result, I used rabl to show the json:

```
object @user_types => false

node(:user_types) {@user_types}
```

This is the output:

```
[
  {
    "user_types": {
      "user": "Administrator",
      "owner": "owner",
      "client": "Customer"
    }
  },
  {
    "user_types": {
      "user": "Administrator",
      "owner": "owner",
      "client": "Customer"
    }
  },
  {
    "user_types": {
      "user": "Administrator",
      "owner": "owner",
      "client": "Customer"
    }
  }
]
```

And I want to output only like this:

```
 {
    "user_types": {
      "user": "Administrator",
      "owner": "owner",
      "client": "Customer"
    }
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "And when I add the code in controller"? Please edit your question to include your controller code.

Comment: @Jordan added controller

Comment: Have you tried a name other than `TYPE`? ActiveRecord might be using that for some reason.

Comment: @tadman, yes I've tried but still the same output.

Comment: Something is redefining this from a Hash to an Array. There's something, somewhere in the code doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rabl is mapping `@user_types`.

In your case, it should be:

```
# xxxx.rabl
object false

node(:user_types) {@user_types}
```

doc: https://github.com/nesquena/rabl#object-assignment

Comment: Yes, thanks! Replacing `object @user_types => false` to `object false` works perfectly.